# Getting Started with Square and Django

Tags: python, django, square-connect, square

I'm trying to get a simple Square credit card form to work on our Django website. I'm new to using Square, but have used similar API's such as Stripe in the past.

To start, I followed along with their [Square Payment Form walkthrough](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/payment-form-walkthrough). I added their SqPaymentForm library and our own javascript file where I initialized a new SqPaymentForm.

The front-end appears to be working and is generating a unique card nonce every time I enter fake credentials.

Next, I submitted the form to our back-end (including the card nonce, in a hidden nonce field).

On the back-end, I've installed the [Square Connect Python SDK](https://github.com/square/connect-python-sdk). I copied their "Charge the card nonce" example as closely as possible, substituting our sandbox access token and location ID:

```
import uuid

import squareconnect
from squareconnect.rest import ApiException
from squareconnect.apis.transactions_api import TransactionsApi

# create an instance of the Transactions API class
api_instance = TransactionsApi()
# setup authorization
api_instance.api_client.configuration.access_token = 'sandbox-access-token'

location_id = 'sandbox-location-id'

nonce = request.POST.get('nonce', 'empty')
if (nonce == 'empty'): print("Throw error")
# print(nonce)

try:
  # Charge
  idempotency_key = str(uuid.uuid1())
  amount = {'amount': 100, 'currency': 'USD'}
  body = {'idempotency_key': idempotency_key, 'card_nonce': nonce, 'amount_money': amount}
  api_response = api_instance.charge(location_id, body)
  print (api_response.transaction)
except ApiException as e:
  print ('Exception when calling TransactionApi->charge: %s\n' % e)
```

I've also tried reformatting this code slightly to fit the example demonstrated in Square's [connect-api-examples on GitHub](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/python_payment).

But, when I test it in localhost (http), using the different demo credentials provided by Square on their [test values page](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/testing/test-values), I consistently get an 'Unauthorized' error from the API:

```
Exception when calling TransactionApi->charge: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict(
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Vary': 'Origin, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Download-Options': 'noopen', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies': 'none', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Date': 'Wed, 31 Jul 2019 20:59:10 GMT', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=60', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=631152000', 'content-length': '119'})
HTTP response body: {"errors":[{"category":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"This request could not be authorized."}]}
```

When I look through the Troubleshooting documentation, it says the likely cause for an [Unauthorized error](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/troubleshooting#unauthorized) is an invalid OAuth token. Yet, none of Square's demos or examples utilize OAuth. I don't understand why OAuth would be necessary for a simple payment form that isn't behind a sign-up page?

I've tried uploading the code to our https website to see if an SSL cert was required, but I get the same error.

Comment: OAuth is definitely not required, but authentication errors imply that the access token is incorrect. Are you sure you're using the access token and not application id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your access token, then your code will work. The location id is also not set, so square sends an error. I had the same problem, and I realized that it was because I forgot to add the access token. Hope that this helps.